# Programmatically install Certificate Revocation List (CRL)

Tags: c#, powershell, scripting, vbscript, batch-file

I need to download and install about 50 CRLs once a week and install them on several Windows servers. Downloading is the easy part, is there a way I could script the CRL import process?

Comment: When you say downloading is the easy part? Can you share your technique that you used to accomplish this. Thanks

Comment: @Raj pretty much every certificate authority or signer will publish a CRL location as part of the certificate metadata. Open up the certificate in question and look for a field called "CRL Distribution Points". Really this is a general question you should ask not just leave as a comment.

Comment: Yes, i am aware of the Distribution points as a field in the certificate. Currently i use Remote Object Retrieval Functions,[CryptoAPI] to retrieve from the CDP's. I also understand that if you just copy the URL and past them in the browser, CRL will get downloaded as well. The reason why i asked you as a comment is that you mentioned that CRL retrieval is the easy part, so i assumed that you have got some utility or something which will do this for you. But obviously my assumption was wrong. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know a way to do it via script. 
Can you write C code?  If I understand what you want to do, you will use the [CryptUiWizImport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380598.aspx) function, and the [CRYPTUI_WIZ_IMPORT_SRC_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380870(VS.85).aspx) structure.

Here's a [sample of code that installs a Cert](http://blogs.msdn.com/alejacma/archive/2008/01/31/how-to-import-a-certificate-without-user-interaction-c-c.aspx); the corresponding CRL import is similar.

**Addendum**:
[This post](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2006/04/25/583236.aspx) points out that Win32 APIs (such as CryptUiWizImport) are not directly accessible from PowerShell, and then describes a possible workaround:  from within the PowerShell script, dynamically generate and compile C# code that does the P/Invoke stuff, and then run the resulting assembly.  This would allow you to do the  CryptUiWizImport strictly from a powershell script, although it would be a pretty exotic one.

Comment: I wrapped the CryptUIWizImport function as a C# console application and it works like a charm for installing both certs and CRLs. Thank you very much!

Comment: You interested in posting the source, to help the next person?

Comment: I would be really interested in the source... for I have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 13):

Here is my final source (slightly scrubbed for the public) - but should work. I won't change the accepted answer, but I do hope this helps (as does upvoting the question and answers!).

**Note:** This will import both a CRL or a regular certificate into the LOCAL MACHINE Trusted Root store. Changing the below `CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE` to `CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER` in the call CertOpenStore will change it to work for the Current User store.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
  class Program
  {
    public struct CRYPTUI_WIZ_IMPORT_SRC_INFO
    {
      public Int32 dwSize;
      public Int32 dwSubjectChoice;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]public String pwszFileName;
      public Int32 dwFlags;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]public String pwszPassword;
    }

    [DllImport("CryptUI.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern Boolean CryptUIWizImport(
      Int32 dwFlags,
      IntPtr hwndParent,
      IntPtr pwszWizardTitle,
      ref CRYPTUI_WIZ_IMPORT_SRC_INFO pImportSrc,
      IntPtr hDestCertStore
    );

    [DllImport("CRYPT32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr CertOpenStore(
      int storeProvider,
      int encodingType,
      IntPtr hcryptProv,
      int flags,
      String pvPara
    );

    public const Int32 CRYPTUI_WIZ_IMPORT_SUBJECT_FILE = 1;
    public const Int32 CRYPT_EXPORTABLE = 0x00000001;
    public const Int32 CRYPT_USER_PROTECTED = 0x00000002;
    public const Int32 CRYPTUI_WIZ_NO_UI = 0x0001;

    private static int CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM = 10;
    private static int CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER = (1 << 16);
    private static int CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE = (2 << 16);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      if (args.Length != 1)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Usage: certimp.exe list.crl");
        Environment.ExitCode = 1;
      }
      else
      {
        IntPtr hLocalCertStore = CertOpenStore(
          CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM,
          0,
          IntPtr.Zero,
          CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE,
          "ROOT"
        );

        CRYPTUI_WIZ_IMPORT_SRC_INFO importSrc = new CRYPTUI_WIZ_IMPORT_SRC_INFO();
        importSrc.dwSize = Marshal.SizeOf(importSrc);
        importSrc.dwSubjectChoice = CRYPTUI_WIZ_IMPORT_SUBJECT_FILE;
        importSrc.pwszFileName = args[0];
        importSrc.pwszPassword = null;
        importSrc.dwFlags = CRYPT_EXPORTABLE | CRYPT_USER_PROTECTED;

        if (!CryptUIWizImport(
            CRYPTUI_WIZ_NO_UI,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            ref importSrc,
            hLocalCertStore
          ))
        {
          Console.WriteLine("CryptUIWizImport error " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
          Environment.ExitCode = -1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note: You can also create an X509Store, Open() it and pass its StoreHandle property as the last argument to CryptUIWizImport.

Comment: Note: Despite what the documentation says, none of the CRYPTUI_WIZ_NO_UI flags prevent a popup dialog that asks "Do you want to replace the current CRL?" when the target store already contains a CRL with the same or newer validity time. (Tested on Win2008 R2)

Comment: Note: For a more direct way of adding a CRL to a Windows certificate store than (potentially) going through a UI, you can P/Invoke the CertAddCRLContextToStore Win32 function from crypt32.dll.

Answer (score 3):

Hm. Is there any reason not to use the certutil.exe utility? I can import a Certificate Revocation List into the appropriate store by running the following command:

```
certutil -addstore CA <FileName>.crl
```

Comment: certutil is not part of a standard installation. I believe it only is installed when certificate services have been installed (though I could be wrong).

Answer (score 1):

In Powershell there is a `Cert:` provider which represents the certificate store. Manipulating it is done via the standard cmdlets so you might be able to integrate a revocation list there somewhere. I just don't know enough about how Windows handles certificates to be of any further help here.

Answer (score 0):

We have to use only Win32 Apis to do this. There is no firstclass C# system APIs to do this. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67814697/3671594